# How to make writings in a readonly filesystem?

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi3, readonly, file-writing

I'm writing a Qt\Qml app for raspberry pi 3b+, and I need to save informations every time an event is triggered.

On production the raspberry's file system will be mounted in readonly and I wish to found the best way to write a file in a not tmpfs partition, for restoring it in case of powerloss.

Only three ways come to mind:

1. in the same thread remount rw before writing and then remount ro after writing, but this slow down my program because it takes around 600 ms to carry out both operations.
2. do the same of 1 but in another thread.
3. Write temporary files in tmpfs partition and then append it to final position through a thread that check for temporary files.

I don't want change the default raspberry filesystem structure (small fat + extendable ext4 ) and I don't want add an external drive.

Comment: 4. Have another location to write the data that can be rw?

Comment: I don't want change the default raspberry filesystem structure (small fat + extendable ext4 ) and I don't want add an external drive. I will modify my question!

Comment: Why don't you want to change the file system structure? Because that's the way to solve this. Alternatively, just make one of the current partitions read-write, if you need to be constantly remounting.

Comment: My app is hosted and runned by another app, so I can't change the enviroment.